# Excel get data from Sharepoint (500) internal Server Error. Exceeds Lookup error. Work around is in Access, want a better idea please?

Tags: excel, sharepoint

The (500) internal Server Error. Exceeds Lookup error. [This](https://natechamberlain.com/2018/09/04/how-to-increase-lookup-column-limit-in-sharepoint-lists/) is a good explanation of the error, or in plain English there is just too many variables on that SharePoint site. My work around is to create a public view on the SharePoint site. Excel cannot see the view, but Access can. Creating anything in Access makes me nervous since it really isn't supported anymore. Does anyone have a better idea? Thank you :-)

--Perhaps a solution can be found in the advanced editor, has anyone used that to find a view or cut down on the amount of incoming data?

Comment: _Creating anything in Access makes me nervous since it really isn't supported anymore_ Wut? Access is supported, it's not going anywhere. Certain features, such as Access web apps, got removed, but Access as a whole is not going anywhere

Comment: Good call out Erik, I just assumed since the latest version I could find was 2016 that Access was support, my mistake :-)